# SparkR collect() and head() error for Spark DataFrame: arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r, apache-spark, parquet, sparkr, apache-spark-sql

I read a parquet file from HDFS system:

```
path<-"hdfs://part_2015"
AppDF <- parquetFile(sqlContext, path)
printSchema(AppDF)

root
 |-- app: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- category: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- date: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- user: binary (nullable = true)

class(AppDF)

[1] "DataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "SparkR"

collect(AppDF)
.....error:
arguments imply differing number of rows: 46021, 39175, 62744, 27137

head(AppDF)
.....error:
arguments imply differing number of rows: 36, 30, 48
```

I've read some thread about this problem. But it's not my case. In fact, I just read a table from the parquet file, and `head()` or `collect()` it. My parquet table is like the following:

```
app   category  date        user
aaa   test      20150101    123
aaa   test      20150102    345
aaa   test      20150103    678
aaaa  testA     20150104    123
aaaa  testA     20150105    234
aaaa  testA     20150106    4345
bbbb  testB     20150101    5435
```

I'm using spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6
And I run this on cluster by using

```
./sparkR --master yarn--client
```

I've also tried it in local, there is the same problem.

```
showDF(AppDF)

+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|        app|   category|       date|       user|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|[B@217fa749|[B@43bfbacd|[B@60810b7a|[B@3818a815|
|[B@5ac31778|[B@3e39f5d5|[B@4f3a92dd| [B@e8013ce|
|[B@7a9440d1|[B@1b2b9836|[B@4b160f29|[B@153d7342|
|[B@7559fcf2|[B@66edb00e|[B@7ec19bec|[B@58e3e3f7|
|[B@598b9ab8|[B@5c5ad3f5|[B@4f11a931|[B@107af885|
|[B@7951ec36|[B@716b0b73|[B@2abce531|[B@576b09e2|
|[B@34560144|[B@7a6d3233|[B@16faf110|[B@34e85d39|
| [B@3406452|[B@787a4528|[B@235282e3|[B@7e0f1732|
|[B@10bc1446|[B@2bd7083f|[B@325e7695|[B@57bb4a08|
|[B@48f98037|[B@7450c04e|[B@61817c8a|[B@7c177a08|
|[B@694ce2dd|[B@36c2512d| [B@f5f7d71|[B@46248d99|
|[B@479dee25|[B@517de3de|[B@1ffb2d9e|[B@236ff079|
|[B@52ac196f|[B@20b9f0d0| [B@f70f879|[B@41c8d7da|
|[B@68d34af3| [B@7ddcd49|[B@72d077a7|[B@545fafd4|
|[B@5610b292|[B@623bbb62|[B@3f8b5150|[B@53877bc7|
|[B@63cf70a8|[B@47ed58c9|[B@2f601903|[B@4e0a2c41|
|[B@7ddf876d|[B@5e3445aa|[B@39c9cc37|[B@6f7e4c84|
|[B@4cd1a74b|[B@583e5453|[B@64124267|[B@6ac5ab84|
|[B@577f9ddf|[B@7b55c859|[B@3cd48a51|[B@25c4eb0a|
|[B@2322f0e5|[B@4af55c68|[B@3285d64a|[B@70b7ae2f|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I've alse tried to read this parquet file in Scala.And do a collect() operation. It seems that everything works well. So it should be an issue specific for SparkR

Comment: The problem is that your file probably has incomplete rows (only 3 instead of 4 items), I do not know how to fix this however as I do not have any experience with parquet files.

Comment: @WannesRosiers, I have checked this table by using HIVE, but there is no incomplete row.

Comment: Could you try this with the Python / Scala shells in Spark ? I'm not sure if this is a problem with the R API or with how the Parquet file is being read in Scala. Also could you try `showDF` and see if that works ?

Comment: @ShivaramVenkataraman, I have tried showDF(). The result is in the update

Comment: @ShivaramVenkataraman, as you mentioned, it's a problem with R API

Comment: I see the problem - Binary column types are not supported properly in the SparkR implementation right now. Is there any way you can change your schema to primitive types (like IntType, StringType etc.) I'll also open a JIRA to track the BinaryType bug in SparkR