# SparkR reading in column as binary instead of string

Tags: sparkr

I have a table in Impala/Hive, which is type def'd as a string:

```
name, type
tdate, string
area, int
```

(for example).

When I read in the Parquet file that this is based on:

```
df<-parquetFile(sqlContext,'/path/to/main/folder')
df
```

It tells me it has `binary` fields?

```
DataFrame[tdate:binary, area:int]
```

How do I get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Linking to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555667/sparkr-collect-and-head-error-for-spark-dataframe-arguments-imply-differing  which seems to have the same issue. Looks like it may be a problem with the R API and unsupported at the moment.

Comment: Apparently when reading a Parquet file created from SparkR it works fine, so it seems to be an issue with not having the metadata available from a table created in Impala?

Comment: Important point - upon testing this is an issue in Java as well, where we have a fix similar to the one below to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is here:

I found the solution to the problem.

We can do the following:

```
sql(sqlContext,'SET spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString=true')
```

This fixes everything.